# requirejs optimizer doesn't generate '.js' version of the text resource

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, yeoman, requirejs-text

In my project I use yeoman (1.0.6). In a fresh webapp copy installed requirejs-text plugin to include **template.html**.

*main.js*

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
        text: '../bower_components/requirejs-text/text'
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'text!../templates.html'], function ($, templates) {
....
```

After building and optimizing a whole project, I expect to have generated templates.js file instead of templates.html ( added
`"optimizeAllPluginResources: true"` as described [here](https://github.com/digitalsadhu/yeoman-require-boilerplate/tree/master/components/text) )

*Gruntfile.js* ( won't paste all code, just optimization settings )

```
....
requirejs: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            optimize: 'none',
            optimizeAllPluginResources: true,
            preserveLicenseComments: false,
            useStrict: true,
            wrap: true
        }
    }
},
....
```

After grunt 'build' task is completed I see that **template.html** content is in **main.js** and there is no generated **templates.js** file

After adding (also have to set in copy task to copy requirejs-text plugin form app to dir folder ):

```
stubModules: ['text'],
exclude: ['text!../templates.html'],
```

files are excluded as expected, but there is still **no templates.js** file. ( get an error as expected: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///...../dist/templates.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. it works fine with local HTTP )

**My question is**: What settings am I missing to generate **templates.js** file with a requirejs optimizer?

p.s. googled, spent all day, tried more than wrote here.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: It seems to me the file is created after the grunt build, but you can't access it because you're accessing it from another origin? (localhost versus remote server? File versus localhost?)

Comment: .js file is not created (what I actually need), .html is copied and I can't access it.

Comment: But the error you're getting is about the .html file. So somewhere in your code it is still referenced?

Comment: Yes, if I understand correctly, it should include code something like define('text!../templates.html', [], function(require){ return require('../templates.js') }) in main.js and generate templates.js

Comment: same issue I cant get these .js file generated, did you finally found an answer?

Comment: didn't solve it, simply require templates.js where I place all code I need.